# Changes in the calling convention to configure a local parallel pool

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

In earlier versions of Matlab (e.g. 2013A) I would set up a local parallel pool using the `matlabpool` function. For example:

```
matlabpool('size') %To determine if a pool was already open
```

and

```
matlabpool(12) %To create a local pool of 12 workers
```

In a more recent version of Matlab (R2015A) this command has been replaced with `parpool`.

1. What version was this change made in (for multi-version code)
2. What are the appropriate equivalent uses of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `parpool` was introduced in R2014A (8.3), and `matlabpool` was removed in R2015A version (8.5). See the parallel toolbox notes for 2014A and 2015A here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html

The equivalent commands are shown below:

```
numWorkers = 12;
if verLessThan('matlab','8.3') %Pre-2014A code
    if matlabpool('size') == 0;  %Skip setup if a pool is already open
        matlabpool(numWorkers);
    end
else                           %2015A or later code
    if isempty(gcp('nocreate'))    %Skip setup if a pool is already open
        parpool('local',numWorkers);
    end
end
```

Comment: Although the change was made permanent in 2015a, the new command was introduced in 2014a, so that 2014a and 2014b will issue a warning if `matlabpool` is used instead of `parpool`. I would suggest making your `verLessThan` cutoff at 8.3 instead of 8.5.